# Cell height is not changing dynamically ios 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have followed this tutorial for dynamic cell height:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

My code is as below:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ChatViewCell *cell=(ChatViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatViewCell"];
    if (cell==nil) {
        for (id currentObject in [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatViewCell" owner:self options:nil]) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (ChatViewCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cell.IBlblDate.text = @"8 th jan,2015";
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
    cell.IBlblMsg.text = @"HelloHelloHelloHelloHello";
    }
    if (indexPath.row==2) {
        cell.IBlblMsg.text = @"HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello";
    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        cell.IBlblMsg.text = @"HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello";
    }
    if (indexPath.row==3) {
        cell.IBlblMsg.text = @"HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello";
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 49;

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ChatViewCell *cell = (ChatViewCell *)[IBtblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setNeedsLayout];

    [cell layoutIfNeeded];


    CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1.0f;
}
```

but I am getting output as below:

[image]
please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: make sure you have set the constraints right.

Comment: @Abhishek I have applied correct leading, trailing and top constarins to labels, still getting this

Comment: can share sample code on github?

Comment: @Abhishek check this dropbox link for code:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8u7p9py0jogsq4n/AAC5VCz2MmNkhSpo7GmIgFD-a?dl=0

Comment: @Abhishek please check my code and let me know as soon as posible, as I am stuck in this

Comment: @Abhishek also I want this to support for ios 7

Comment: Check this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stxdynamictableview it will help you

Comment: @Abhishek can ypu please check my code in tell me what could be issue?

Comment: You haven't set constraint properly

Comment: @Abhishek can you tell me that which constrains I need to set? can you explain me my mistake?